# How to solve this probability question

Tags: probability

The probability that the 8-hour bus, which travels from New York to Washington, depart with $m$ minutes of delay is $p_m=3^{-m}$ $(m=1,2,3,\cdots;m\neq0)$. For regulatory reasons, departures never goes ahead.

1. What is the probability that the bus leaves at 8 o'clock?
2. Show that the probability that the bus leaves at 8:10 is twice the probability of departing after 8:10.

Comment: Hint for the first: the bus will leave either at 8 or it will leave some number of minutes after 8.  If we were to add all of these probabilities together it should add up to exactly one.  The formula for evaluating a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) should be useful here.

Comment: There is no frame of reference.  The question bothers me @JMoravitz

Comment: @Satish I'm entirely convinced that there is a translation difficulty here, that the phrase "the 8-hour bus" was intended to mean that the bus is scheduled to depart at 8 o'clock.  The probability that the bus in fact leaves at 8:01 would be $p_1$, at 8:15 would be $p_{15}$, etc...

Comment: You mean $p_8+p_{m minutes after}=1$, so $p_8=1-p_{m minutes after}$. So $p_8=1-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^m}$.@JMoravitz

Comment: I would not have written it as $p_8$ because the notation $p_m$ was defined to be the probability that the departure was delayed by exactly $m$ minutes.  $p_8$ should have represented the probability that the departure was delayed by 8 minutes, i.e. left at 8:08.  You should have used $p_0$ or some entirely different choice of notation which does not overlap with previously defined notation in the problem.  Apart from that, yes, that is what I was pointing you towards.  Now you need to do the calculations.

Comment: Oh. You're right @JMoravitz, I was wrong with the notation.